# Finding the coefficient of a variable given the coefficient of another

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, physics

I'm working with the following Kepler equation:

$$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{r^3}{GM}}$$

Which I have rearranged to find M:

$$M=\frac{r^3}{G(\frac{T}{2\pi})^2}$$

I have chosen the following values:

$r=100$
$M=100$
$T=76911340.145$
$G = 6.67408 × 10^{11}$

And now if I was to divide $r$ and $G$ by $1000$, I would like to know what coefficient must be applied to M to maintain the same value for T.

I have already managed to figure this out (somewhat) if I divide by $10$ instead: **(I am looking for a general solution)**

Given $r_2=\frac{r_1}{10}$, $G_2=\frac{G_1}{10}$, $M_2=\alpha M_1$:

$$\alpha=(\frac{1}{10})^2 \therefore M_2=(\frac{1}{10})^2M_1$$

And in more general terms:

$d=\frac{1}{10}, r_2=dr_1, G_2=dG_1, M_2=d^2M_1$

However my "proof" breaks down now when I use $d=\frac{1}{1000}$ and I do not know how to continue.

My attempt so far:

*Long way:*

$$M_2=\frac{(\frac{r_1}{1000})^3}{\frac{G_1}{1000}(\frac{T}{2\pi})^2}=1 × 10^{-5}$$

*"Proof":*

$$M_2=(\frac{1}{1000})^2M_1=1 × 10^{-4}$$

Clearly these two are not equal. Can somebody kindly please point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** Fixed question based on the results of the accepted answer.

Comment: Note: I do not know how to word the title. If I may use better wording, please let me know and I will change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see how you ended up with $d^3$ because it should be $d^2$:

$$2\pi\sqrt{\frac{(dr)^3}{(dG)(d^2M)}} = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{d^3r^3}{d^3GM}} = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{r^3}{GM}} = T.$$

Comment: I'm not so sure you understand the question. Given $d=10$, $d^{3}M$ will indeed work but it doesn't for $d=1000$ hence why I'm searching for a general equation.

Comment: @FinnRayment No, what I was trying to tell you is that you made a mistake in your example for $d = 10$. The correct value is $d^2$ as I just showed you above.

Comment: Ah! My apologies, you are indeed correct, thank you. (Just verified and my proof still does not work)

Comment: @FinnRayment Are you saying you tried with $d^2$ and it still did not work?

Comment: Yes, I have now updated the question with corrected values for everything.

Comment: @FinnRayment You did another mistake, I'm afraid. You should get $10^{-6}$ in both cases. Besides, above I _proved_ to you that $d^2$ is correct.

Comment: Hmmm... I have no idea how! $d=\frac{1}{10}$, $r_2=dr$, $M_2=\frac{100}{100}=d^{2}M_1$ however $d=\frac{1}{100}$, $r_2=dr$, $M_2=\frac{100}{1000}\neq d^{2}M_1$. (Using the actual Kepler equation to find these results)

Comment: $M_2 = \frac{100}{1000000} = \frac{1}{10000} = d^2M_1$ if $d = \frac{1}{100}$.

Comment: Right! I honestly cannot do maths tonight... My apologies and thank you for your patience.

Comment: @FinnRayment Haha, no worries, take yourself a break. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you divide  $r$ and $G$ by $q=1000=10^3$ then $r^3/G$ will be divided by $(10^3)^3/10^3=10^6=q^2$. So you will get the same $T$ when you will divide $M$ by same number, that is $q^2=10^6$ (or multiplied by $10^{-6}$).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a generalised equation for this where I may use it for anything other than straight multiples of 10? Edit: Didn't see your edit with $q^2$ sorry.